# If $G$ is a gp, then $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$. Why is it not true that $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying Abstract Algebra (Group Theory) for the first time, and I found a lemma that states:
Let $G$ be a group, and $a,b$ in $G$
Then $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$

Proof:
$$(b^{-1}a^{-1})ab = b^{-1}eb = b^{-1}b = e$$
$$ab(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = e \implies (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$$

My professor mentioned that the other way around is incorrect, so I tried writing out the proof, and it makes sense why it isn't correct, but I want to guarantee that I understand why it's wrong:

$$(a^{-1}b^{-1})ab = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$$
Here, are we not allowed to cancel out the elements a and b if their inverses are not next to them? Why wouldn't it, if groups must maintain associativity?

Comment: The last line states "Why wouldn't it, if groups must maintain associativity?"  Could you elaborate on what the pronoun "it" refers to?

Comment: Why do the elements a and b not cancel out with their respective inverses to the identity?

Comment: The expression would be $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. How does it cancel out? Groups need not be commutative in general. Associativity means $(ab)c=a(bc)$, and it only allows you to omit parenthesis, but you cannot change the order of multiplication.

Comment: Yes, I see it now.
So we can say that (ab)^-1 = a^-1b^-1 if the group is abelian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse of a product in a group can be written as the product of the inverses of each element in reverse order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119626/inverse-of-a-product-in-a-group-can-be-written-as-the-product-of-the-inverses-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of an element $x$ in a group is an element $y$ in the group such that $xy=e$ and $yx=e$ where $e$ is the identity.  In other words, the inverse is defined in terms of a *property it has with respect to $x$*.  The proof that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is merely checking that $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ has the correct property to be the inverse of $ab$.

When $a$ and $b$ commute, then $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.  The problem with this in general is that one can't be certain that $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})=e$ since we don't have cancellation.  Say, for instance, that we wanted to cancel $a$ and $a^{-1}$ in $aba^{-1}$ so that $aba^{-1}=b$.  If we multiply by $a$ on the right, we get that $ab=ba$, which is exactly the equality that shows that $a$ and $b$ commute.  Therefore, we see that $aba^{-1}=b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ commute.

If $a$ and $b$ do not commute, then $aba^{-1}=c\not=b$, and, since inverses are unique, $c^{-1}\not=b^{-1}$, so $cb^{-1}\not=e$.  Therefore, $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ is not the inverse of $ab$.

Comment: Excellent, cleared up my confusion on the problem. Thank you

Comment: Clear, clear and clear explanation.